# Is it "riche" or "suave" in the poem "Le Chat"(Baudelaire)?

Tags: poésie

I'm reading the poem "Le Chat" of Charles Baudelaire.

On [wiki](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Fleurs_du_mal/1857/Le_Chat_(%C2%AB_Dans_ma_cervelle_se_prom%C3%A8ne_%C2%BB)), it says

> Elle est toujours suave et profonde.

, while on another book, it reads

> Elle est toujours riche et profonde.

May I ask, which one is the right version?

The full poem is as below:

> LE CHAT
>
> Dans ma cervelle se promène,
> Ainsi qu’en son appartement,
> Un beau chat, fort, doux et charmant ;
> Quand il miaule, on l’entend à peine,
>
> Tant son timbre est tendre et discret ;
> Mais que sa voix s’apaise ou gronde,
> Elle est toujours suave et profonde.
> C’est là son charme et son secret.
>
> Cette voix, qui perle et qui filtre
> Dans mon fonds le plus ténébreux,
> Me remplit comme un vers nombreux
> Et me pénètre comme un philtre.
>
> Elle endort les plus cruels maux
> Et contient toutes les extases ;
> Pour dire les plus longues phrases,
> Elle n’a pas besoin de mots.
>
> Non, il n’est pas d’archet qui morde
> Sur mon cœur, parfait instrument,
> Et fasse plus royalement
> Chanter sa plus vibrante corde
>
> Que ta voix, chat mystérieux,
> Chat séraphique, chat étrange,
> En qui tout est, comme en un ange,
> Aussi subtil qu’harmonieux.

Comment: There were two editions of *Les Fleurs du mal* published during Baudelaire's lifetime. It's entirely possible he revised some of his poems between these editions.

Comment: https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Fleurs_du_mal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Suave* was in the first edition.

I guess readers questioned the validity of the octosyllable so Baudelaire replaced *suave* (2 syllables in classical poetry) by *riche* (1 syllable).

Comment: eh... pls could you elaborate a bit why *suave* has 2 syllables? the *ve* in *suave* doesn't count, same as the *che* in *riche*, right? do you mean *sua* has 2 syllables?

Comment: Yes, the *U* and *A* of *suave*, merged in both old French (/swɛf/) and spoken French /sɥav/, are generally separated in classical poetry /su.av/. *Suave* still has these two syllables in careful speech: https://youglish.com/pronounce/suave/french?

Comment: Baudelaire also revised *Au lecture*, undoubtedly for the same reason, changing *Dans nos cerveaux malsains, comme un million d’helminthes,* to *Serré, fourmillant, comme un million d'helminthes,* I suppose poetry critics were really picky back then.

Comment: And now I'm wondering whether Baudelaire was trying to loosen the strictures of classical French poetry, the way Victor Hugo did with the *alexandrin ternaire*. If he was, he got so much negative feedback that he gave up.

Comment: @PeterShor Baudelaire did certainly innovate in that area. In the *suave* case, the pronunciation was (and is still) undecided depending on the speaker so it was simpler for him to avoid the issue by using something different. In another similar word of the same poem, *miaule*, Baudelaire count a single syllable so match modern poetry and spoken French (classical would have been "*mi-aule*").